# Do we need to avoid reflection when design scala libraries?

Tags: scala, reflection, argonaut

Take `argonaut` for example, in some of our projects, when there is the need to handle JSON, people will use argonaut for that, and hardcoding the fields, like:

```
implicit def AddressCodecJson: CodecJson[Address] =
    casecodec3(Address.apply, Address.unapply)("street", "number", "post_code")
```

If there is a big case class, the list will be very long:

```
implicit def AddressCodecJson: CodecJson[Address] =
    casecodec12(Address.apply, Address.unapply)("street", "number", "post_code", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...")
```

My question is why do we need to hardcode them, rathar than get the field by reflection?

Is there any technical problem, or people just don't like using reflection when design Scala libraries?

Comment: Speaking generally, reflection is slow, not thread-safe and, the most important, doesn't prove anything at compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very clear whether you are trying to parse the json generically. I am assuming that you want to parse any json generically. 
If that is the case, instead of creting the implicit conversion for each of the case classes, you can use `json4s` to do that. In that case, you do not need to provide the implcit conversion for each class. We are using it extensively in our project. 
You only need to give implicit converter for each types (for eg: how to covert java.sql.timestamp, java.sql.Date, Joda-Time etc).

Probably, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335454/converting-json-in-one-format-to-another-in-scala/30342337#30342337) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for recommending `json4s`, I like it and use it in my personal project. I just not clear why people want to use an approach that need to hardcode everything. I asked some of that, and they are not very clear, just copy from older projects

Comment: @Freewind: I have also wondered the same.But may be for small projects, people find it easier to have case class wise implicit conversion. But i belive that it is too much heacache to manage the so many implicit conversions. I am not sure how much performance impact it can make, but I prefer generic solution, since it makes life easier as the project grows.